# creating files in c getting abort : 6 error

Tags: c, memory-management

the loop only goes through 0-9 the out put is this.
the error im getting is abort 6 , im not sure what it means

```
   1.txt 38 
   2.txt 5 
   3.txt 6 
   4.txt 24 
   5.txt 17 
   6.txt 12 
   7.txt 34 
   8.txt 30 
   9.txt 6 
   Abort trap: 6
```

also the code below creates the same random numbers every run how can i make it more random

```
void save(char *, int );
void create(char *, int );
void close();
FILE * list;
FILE * file;
int main(void)
{
    char ext[4] = ".txt";
    static const int MIN = 1 ;
    static const int MAX = 40 ;
    int rdm , fsize;


    list = fopen("filelist.txt","w");
    char str[2];

    //char str3[6];
    list = fopen("filelist.txt", "a+");


    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ )
    {
        sprintf(str,"%d",i+1);

        char * str3 = (char *) calloc(1,1 + strlen(str)+ strlen(ext) );
        //file = fopen(str3,"r");
        strcat(str3,str);
        strcat(str3, ext);
        // printf("%s \n",ext);
        //strcat(str3, ext);
        rdm = (rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN);
        printf("%s %i \n",str3, rdm);
        save(str3 , rdm);
        create(str3 , rdm);
        // printf("%s \n",ext);

    }
    close();
}

void save(char * fname , int sz)
{

    fprintf(list , "%s %d %d \n" , fname , sz , sz*512 );

}

void create(char * fname , int sz)
{
    file = fopen(fname, "w");
    fseek(file, sz*512, SEEK_SET);
    fputc('\n', file);
    fclose(file);

}

void close()
{
    fclose(list);

}
```

Comment: `char ext[4] = ".txt";`. That does not produce a valid NUL terminated string. Change it to `char ext[] = ".txt"` or  `char ext[5] = ".txt"`.

Comment: For one thing, `str` is too small.  You need 2 bytes for the number (since it goes as high as 10) plus 1 byte for the terminating null byte.  That's 3 bytes.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three things here:

Firstly, your main function is returning int:

```
int main()
```

So, in the success case for running your code, you should return 0 at the very last line:

```
...//all other lines
return 0; //no error
```

Secondly, rand() is pseudo random random. It generates pre-determined random number everytime according to the random number seed used. to make your rand() value change everytime, consider of having time as random seed in srand(). Then your random values will change according to the time.

```
#include <time.h>
...
srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed
//do it once before you use rand()
```

Thirdly, as commented, your char arrays size seem to be to small:

```
char ext[5] = ".txt"; //should be 5, the last one will be \0
...
char str[15]; //should be large enough for your text
```